# Animated appearance of Photoshop layers

Tags: animation, photoshop, layer

I'm working with a Photoshop document that has over 1,000 layers in it (1052, to be precise).  The file itself is a collage and each layer is an individual image within that collage.  So, when all layers are visible it's a complex collage of 1052 overlapping images.  What I have been trying to do is create an animation of the collage assembly so that, for instance, layer 0 appears and then layer 1, layer 2, etc. and **when each layer appears the previous layer also stays visible**.

I have been able to make a frame animation, to which I've then added all other layers as frames but in this case the animation I create just makes each new frame/layer visible on its own, and making the previous layer(s) invisible.  I've gone through the first several frames, manually keeping the previous layer/frame visible but I'm hoping there's a way to do this more automatically.

Is there an approach or a setting I'm missing that will allow me to automagically create this animation, keeping each frame visible as the next frame also becomes visible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to write a script to automate the process of switching on certain layers and then saving out that as an image, & iterate through the psd. But what have you tried?

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't yet tried scripting at all but it sounds like maybe I'll need to look into that.  I've tried changing some settings in the create frame animation panel and I've tried turning all layers on or off when creating a frame animation.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the premise of want you want is to go through all layers, switching on and off the viability as you go. Or switch them all off before you start, and get the code to loop through all the layers. Also as you are starting out, get rid of any groups, it'll just be easier. Make a copy of the psd without them if you have to.

In Photoshop scripting, the top most layer is 0. The next one below is 1 etc. It's easier to count backwards over the loop

```
for (var i = numOfLayers -1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

The visibility of each layer is controlled with:

```
theLayer.visible = true; // visible
thatLayer.visible = false; // not visible
```

So in short you'll have something like this:

```
// WITH ALL THE LAYERS VISIBILITY SWITCHED OFF TO START WITH!

// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO; // OFF 

// call the source document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

// get the number of layers in the PSD
var numOfLayers = srcDoc.layers.length;

var myFolder = "D:\\temp\\";


// main loop
// ignore background
for (var i = numOfLayers -2; i >= 0  ; i--)
{

    var docName = "image_" + i + ".jpg";

    // get a reference to the layers as you go up
    var thisLayer = srcDoc.layers[i];

    thisLayer.visible = true;

    // duplicate image into new document
    duplicate_it(docName);

    // active document is now the NEW one!

    // flatten it
    activeDocument.flatten();

    jpeg_it(myFolder + docName, 12);

    // close the image WITHOUT saving as we've just saved it
    app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);

    // make the source document the active document
    app.activeDocument = srcDoc;

    // switch OFF the layer
    thisLayer.visible = false;
}


// function DUPLICATE IT (str)
// --------------------------------------------------------
function duplicate_it(str)
{
  // duplicate image into new document
  if (arguments.length == 0) str = "temp";

  var id428 = charIDToTypeID( "Dplc" );
  var desc92 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id429 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
  var ref27 = new ActionReference();
  var id430 = charIDToTypeID( "Dcmn" );
  var id431 = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
  var id432 = charIDToTypeID( "Frst" );
  ref27.putEnumerated( id430, id431, id432 );
  desc92.putReference( id429, ref27 );
  var id433 = charIDToTypeID( "Nm  " );
  desc92.putString( id433, str ); // name
  executeAction( id428, desc92, DialogModes.NO );
}



// function JPEG IT (file path + file name, jpeg quality)
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
function jpeg_it(filePath, jpgQuality)
{

  if(! jpgQuality) jpgQuality = 12;

  // jpg file options
  var jpgFile = new File(filePath);
  jpgSaveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions();
  jpgSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.OPTIMIZEDBASELINE;
  jpgSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
  jpgSaveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;
  jpgSaveOptions.quality = jpgQuality;

  activeDocument.saveAs(jpgFile, jpgSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  Thank you for this very thorough response.  As I understand it, the result of this script will be a series of individual images that can then be assembled into an animation of some sort.  I was looking specifically to the Frame Animation functionality in PS but this also seems to accomplish the goal.  I'll give it a try